# Creating a line plot in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I wanted to create an interactive shiny app to show the graph from chosen variable

Part of the data below:

```
> dput(data_3[1:6,])
structure(list(date = structure(c(18264, 18265, 18266, 18267, 
18268, 18271), class = "Date"), code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AAPL", "AMZN", "BABA", "FB", "GOOG", 
"INTC", "MSFT", "SAP"), class = "factor"), close_price = c(3.997768, 
3.660714, 3.714286, 3.392857, 3.553571, 3.491071), volume = c(133949200, 
128094400, 194580400, 191993200, 115183600, 126266000), company = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alibaba", "Amazon", "Apple", 
"Facebook", "Google", "Intel", "Microsoft", "SAP"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And below is my shiny code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Application title"),
  sidebarPanel('Things to put on the side',
               selectInput("var_selection", label = "Please choose a company...",
                           choices = list("Alibaba" = 'Alibaba',
                                          "Amazon" = 'Amazon',
                                          "Apple" = 'Apple',
                                          "Facebook" = 'Facebook',
                                          "Google" = 'Google',
                                          "Intel" = 'Intel',
                                          "Microsoft" = 'Microsoft',
                                          "SAP" = 'SAP'),
                           selected = 'Alibaba'),
               selectInput("var_selection_2", label = "Please choose type of share...",
                           choices = list("Closing Price" = 'close_price ',
                                          "Share Volume" = ' volume'),
                           selected = 'close_price')),
  mainPanel('Main panel of the app',
            plotOutput('myplot')),
  position = 'left')


server <- function(input, output){
  output$myplot <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(data = data_3, aes(x = date, y = "input$var_selection2", color= 'input$var_selection'))+
      geom_line(aes(y = 'input$var_selection')
                )
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I end up getting a result like this and it seems that it is not that interactive, please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: (1) `y = "input$var_selection2"` is telling `ggplot2` that the y value is a static string. Nothing in R works in a way where it takes a user-defined string and automatically parses out the code (that's prone to code-injection). Look into programmatic use of `ggplot2`, perhaps with `aes_string(x="date",y=input$var_selection)` or similar. (2) It seems like you either want to filter your data based on `var_selection` or just highlight data that matches it. `ggplot2` isn't going to know what to do without you defining what that is (it isn't clear to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter` and `aes_string`:

```
  output$myplot <- renderPlot(
    {
    req(input$type)
    data <- data_3 %>% filter(company == input$company)
    ggplot(data = data)+geom_line(aes_string(x = "date", y = input$type))
    }
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Application title"),
    sidebarPanel('Things to put on the side',
                 selectInput("company", label = "Please choose a company...",
                             choices = list("Alibaba" = 'Alibaba',
                                            "Amazon" = 'Amazon',
                                            "Apple" = 'Apple',
                                            "Facebook" = 'Facebook',
                                            "Google" = 'Google',
                                            "Intel" = 'Intel',
                                            "Microsoft" = 'Microsoft',
                                            "SAP" = 'SAP'),
                             selected = 'Alibaba'),
                 selectInput("type", label = "Please choose type of share...",
                             choices = list("Closing Price" = 'close_price ',
                                            "Share Volume" = ' volume'),
                             selected = 'close_price')),
    mainPanel('Main panel of the app',
              plotOutput('myplot')),
    position = 'left')


server <- function(input, output){
  output$myplot <- renderPlot(
    {
    req(input$type)
    data <- data_3 %>% filter(company == input$company)
    ggplot(data = data)+geom_line(aes_string(x = "date", y = input$type))
      
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you select `Apple` : this is the only company having data in the example dataset you provided

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the reply. However, how should I change the code if I want to plot multiple companies into the plot. I tried changing it to "checkboxGroupInput", but then I assume changes are needed in the ggplot, but I couldn't figure it out. Thank You

Comment: Hi, to answer your last question, you could use the `multiple=T` argument of `selectInput` to choose many companies and then filter by `filter(company %in% input$company)`